# convert xml to json error

Tags: php, json, xml

the xml i am recieving looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ChangePassPhraseRequestResponse 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="www.envmgr.com/LabelService">
    <Status>2012</Status>
    <ErrorMessage>Account Error encountered (Log ID: 11845)</ErrorMessage>
</ChangePassPhraseRequestResponse>
```

i am attempting to encode to json as such (where xml = above response)

```
$data =  simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo json_encode($data);
```

error i am getting is:

```
simplexml_load_string(): namespace warning : xmlns: URI www.envmgr.com/LabelService is not absolute 
SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the xmlns URL (www.envmgr.com/LabelService) does not have scheme (http:// OR https://) specified. if possible add that to the xmlns url or try to suppress warnings using forllowing code:

```
$data =  simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING );
echo json_encode($data);
```

Check here : https://eval.in/532347

Comment: i went with this except using as such:    new SimpleXMLElement($xml,LIBXML_NOWARNING);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_replace()` for removing namespace.

```
$xml_string = preg_replace('/xmlns[^=]*="[^"]*"/i', '', $xml);
$data =  simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Result:**

```
{"Status":"2012","ErrorMessage":"Account Error encountered (Log ID: 11845)"}
```